# SwiftUI: Как скрыть DatePicker после выбора даты

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

Я вызываю календарь и мне необходимо после выбора даты скрывать календарь.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать

```
    import SwiftUI

struct HabitsView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedDate: Date = Date()
    @State private var today: Date = Date()
    @State private var isShowCalendar = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                
                if isShowCalendar {
                    Form {
                        Text("\(today)")
                        DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                            .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            .navigationBarTitle("Habits", displayMode: .large)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно следить за изменением selectedDate и скрывать календарь, по Вашему примеру:

```
DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date)
    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
    .onChange(of: selectedDate, perform: { value in
        isShowCalendar = false
    })
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Это решило мою проблему